# Titanium. Selection in pickerview to bring me to a new window

Tags: javascript, titanium

How do i code a pickerview where i select one of the pickerRow and it brings me to a new window?

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  exitOnClose: true,
  layout: 'vertical'
});

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
  top:50
});

var data = [];
data[0]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Home'});
data[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'About Us'});
data[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Contact us'});

picker.add(data);
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

win.add(picker);
win.open();

// must be after picker has been displayed
picker.setSelectedRow(0, 2, false); // select Contact Us
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an **eventLsitener** on the basis of change and then open window whichever you want to

```
picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    alert(e.row.title);
})
```

Thanks